# Combine a "Select" insert for some rows and "Values" insert for other rows in same query - mysql

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I've looked for an answer to this but can't seem to find anything that covers it.
Is it possible to combine these 2 queries (which work individually) into a single query?
Qry 1) This inserts $ID (as a variable) and a name pulled from TableB, (which corresponds with that ID) into TableA. This creates a single row in TableA.

```
INSERT INTO `TableA`(`ID`,`Name`) 
            SELECT $ID, Name 
            from `TableB` 
            WHERE `ID`='$ID';
```

Qry 2) This inserts $ID (as a variable) and a name (as text) into TableA. This creates a single row in TableA.

```
INSERT INTO `TableA`(`ID`,`Name`) 
            VALUES ('$ID','Changeme!');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use column name in select statement instead of `$ID`

```
INSERT INTO TableA(ID,Name) 
SELECT TableB.ID, TableB.Name from TableB WHERE TableB.ID='$ID'
UNION ALL
SELECT $ID as ID,'changeme!' as name;
```

Using `union` to combine the records.

Comment: I see where you you're coming from CM and thanks but these 2 queries do exactly what I need them to do already. I just wonder if there's a way to combine them into 1. 

    $ID =999
    Qry 1 result inserted into TableA:
    999, Mark Twain

    Qry 2 result inserted into TableA:
    999, ChangeMe!

Comment: Thanks very much @Code-Monk. That did the trick. "UNION ALL" is the way to go! :)